# Hours of availability

Tags: phrase-request, american-english, translation, writing

Is it correct to say:

> I will be available Friday from 10 am.

I'm actually looking for the english equivalent of

> *Je serai disponible vendredi à partir de 10h*.

Comment: _"I will be available on Friday from 10am onwards."_

Answer (score 4):

"From" is correct but slightly odd without a matching "to". A more common usage for open-ended times would be "starting at 10 a.m.".